# Sinatra app deploys to Heroku, but Textile markup not wrapped in HAML layout

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, haml, textile

I've written a small Sinatra application (version 1.1.2) and deployed it successfully to Heroku, with just one small problem.  One of the views, *views/about.textile*, is not wrapped properly by the layout, written in HAML.  The textile renders correctly, but the CSS and a menu bar provided by *views/layout.haml* do not appear on the About page.

In my application file *main.rb*, I have:

```
configure do
  set :textile, :layout_engine => :haml
end

get "/about" do
  textile :about
end
```

RedCloth is specified in *Gemfile* and I have *require "redcloth"* in *config.ru*.

All of the required gems are installed correctly when I push to Heroku.

The *about.textile* view displays correctly when I run the app locally using *shotgun* or *rackup*.

I wondered if anyone else has seen a similar problem, or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this problem too with some rails apps. The problem was for me: Locally my app runs with thin and on production server with mongrel. So you can investigate if the app runs on heroku with the same server as local. I switched to thin on production too, this fixed the problem for me. Look here how to change webserver on heroku: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3#webserver (you have to change the comamnd to fit your sinatra app)

Comment: Thanks, that may well be the solution.  My quick fix is in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to my own question was simply to stick with haml (use file *about.haml*) and include the textile in that file, like so:

```
:textile
  h1. Text goes here...
```

Works just fine: [example page](http://pmretract.heroku.com/about).